# How I can store matching character in new array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to store an element in a new array. Below is my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < namea1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < namea2.length; j++) {
        if (namea1[i] == namea2[j]) {
            // ans=new char[shojib[i]];
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

My array is defined as follows.

```
String name1 = "shojib";
String name2 = "farhana";
int count = 0;
char[] namea1 = name1.toCharArray();
char[] namea2 = name2.toCharArray();
```

I want to store all matching characters to a new array.

Comment: @JunedAhsan, `h` is common.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Set` if only unique matching characters are required:

Sample code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class IntersectionChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findMatchingChars("shojib", "farhana");
        findMatchingChars("one", "onetwothere");
        findMatchingChars("temp", "test");
        findMatchingChars("dis", "connected");
        findMatchingChars("null", "empty");
    }

    private static void findMatchingChars(String a, String b) {
        Set<Character> namea1Chars = new HashSet<Character>();
        Set<Character> namea2Chars = new HashSet<Character>();

        for (char c : a.toCharArray()) {
            namea1Chars.add(c);
        }

        for (char c : b.toCharArray()) {
            namea2Chars.add(c);
        }

        namea1Chars.retainAll(namea2Chars);

        System.out.println("Common Chars in " + a + " & " + b + " are => " + namea1Chars);
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
Common Chars in shojib & farhana are => [h]
Common Chars in one & onetwothere are => [e, n, o]
Common Chars in temp & test are => [e, t]
Common Chars in dis & connected are => [d]
Common Chars in null & empty are => []
```

If you want to capture the all the occurrences then use `List` instead (though there will be performance impact:

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IntersectionChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findMatchingChars("shojib", "farhana");
        findMatchingChars("one", "onetwothere");
        findMatchingChars("tempt", "test");
        findMatchingChars("dis", "connected");
        findMatchingChars("null", "empty");
    }

    private static void findMatchingChars(String a, String b) {
        List<Character> namea1Chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
        List<Character> namea2Chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (char c : a.toCharArray()) {
            namea1Chars.add(c);
        }

        for (char c : b.toCharArray()) {
            namea2Chars.add(c);
        }
        namea1Chars.retainAll(namea2Chars);
        System.out.println("Common Chars in " + a + " & " + b + " are => " + namea1Chars);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Common Chars in shojib & farhana are => [h]
Common Chars in one & onetwothere are => [o, n, e]
Common Chars in tempt & test are => [t, e, t]
Common Chars in dis & connected are => [d]
Common Chars in null & empty are => []
```

You can also use `Map` for better performance

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class IntersectionChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        findMatchingChars("shojib", "farhana");
        findMatchingChars("one", "onetwothere");
        findMatchingChars("tempt", "test");
        findMatchingChars("dis", "connected");
        findMatchingChars("null", "empty");
    }

    private static void findMatchingChars(String a, String b) {
        System.out.print("Common Chars in " + a + " & " + b + " are => [");
        Map<Character, Integer> aCharCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for (char c : a.toCharArray()) {
            if(aCharCount.containsKey(c)) {
                aCharCount.put(c, aCharCount.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                aCharCount.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

        for (char c : b.toCharArray()) {
            if(aCharCount.containsKey(c)) {
                System.out.print(c + ", ");
                if (aCharCount.get(c) == 1) {
                    aCharCount.remove(c);
                } else {
                    aCharCount.put(c, aCharCount.get(c) - 1);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Common Chars in shojib & farhana are => [h, ]
Common Chars in one & onetwothere are => [o, n, e, ]
Common Chars in tempt & test are => [t, e, t, ]
Common Chars in dis & connected are => [d, ]
Common Chars in null & empty are => []
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution, since it'll only tell which letters match, not how many matching occurences

Comment: Did you check the performance difference on the `HashMap` solution? I'm not sure if my results are off due to using a mobile IDE, but it could be possible seeing how you are auto-boxing every key and value entered into the map. You should check, and report the difference in timing

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name1 = "sfhojib";
        String name2 = "farhana";
        int count = 0;
        char[] namea1 = name1.toCharArray();
        char[] namea2 = name2.toCharArray();

        List list = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < namea1.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < namea2.length ; j++) {
                if (namea1[i] == namea2[j]) {
                    list.add(namea1[i]);
                }
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
f
h
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ArrayList. Try below..

```
List<Character> match = new ArrayList<Character>();

//...
// If chars are matching
match.add(namea1[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the array outside of the loop, or you'll create a new array each time you get a matching char.

You could use an `ArrayList<Character>` since you aren't sure what the size of the array will be (then use `list.toArray(...)`), but your primitive chars will be auto-boxed and unboxed every time you add/get from the list. If you don't wanna do this, your best choice is to use the length of the longest name for the `char[]` containing the matches, then manually trimming it.

As for matching, you could add the letter to the list, then remove it from each word, although youd need some kind of 'empty' char to replace the letter, that you know wont be in any names.

**Doesn't use `ArrayList`**

```
char[] name1 = "shojaaaaib".toCharArray();
char[] name2 = "farhana".toCharArray();
char[] matches = new char[name2.length];
final char placeHolder = '~';

firstName:
for(int i = 0; i < name1.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < name2.length; j++)
        if(name1[i] == name2[j])
            for(int k = 0; k < matches.length; k++) //add to matches index if possible
                if(matches[k] == 0) { //if not set yet
                       matches[k] = name1[i];
                    name1[i] = name2[j] = placeHolder;
                    continue firstName;
                }

System.out.println(matches);
```

This will print

```
haaa
```

Since there's 1 matching `h` and 2 matching `a`s